# How do I convert a string to an int and use it as value

Tags: php, datetime

I am having some trouble when I am trying to plus my string as I tried to convert it into a int. Heres my code:

I tried making this updating the time, for example `$time` is `"60"` and `$tm` is a defenision of a int named `$tp` which pluses with time.

```
  $time = $time + intval($time);
  $tm = $tp + $time;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using  date('u') ?

Comment: Time is in datetime format? Have you used `strtotime(...)`?

Comment: Maybe they're just trying to concatenate the time into a string, but the question is worded poorly.

Comment: I am currently making a program which connects to my url and updates the value defined, for example if I do https://mywebsite.com/updatetime?time=60 it gets the value it is on and pluses it with the time defined. I already made it update in my database but in this case the value doesn't apply with the value I defiened which basically is $time

Comment: Hopefully that isn't supposed to be a secure feature, using $_GET is risky.

Comment: Why aren't you just using unix time stamp? seems it would be so much easier.

Comment: If I am gonna be totally honest I use $_GET, I am not so good at using php.

Comment: You should send it as hidden data in a $_POST, so at least it is controlled by a form submission, and anyone cannot just type in whatever value they want into the address bar.

Comment: But they can type any value they want in the form. User controlled data is never to be trusted alone.

Comment: That's only the BEGINNING of making it secure. PHP side would need to check the data received and make sure it is safe.

Comment: Anyway, back to the question... I'd be using unix time stamp, which is a counter in seconds from a specific point in the past. It is easy to use and you can compare curent unix time with submitted time and subtract.

Comment: Okay I will try remake my code a little more, thanks a lot of for the suggestions, I found a solution to update the value. Thanks again!

Comment: php is more forgiving with mixing data types than C or C++, and it MAY just convert simple numbers from a text field into usable ints on its own, so long as it is just the number being sent as text, not mixed with actual text.

Comment: I will keep in my mind what you told me, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submission page would look something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$time = date('u');
```

Now, you're getting the time when the php page is loaded, and you don't need to use get OR post. Just compare $time with whatever you have stored in your database to see how many seconds there are between them, and update however you want.

```
<connect to database and retrieve $dbtime>
$elapsedTime = $dbtime - $time;
if($elapsedTime <= 60)
{
// success
}
else
{
// failure 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let just define $time variable

```
$time = "60"; //you said it is a string and this one is a string
$time = $time+intval($time);
echo $time; //output is 120
```

However, you don't need to use intval function

```
$time = "60"; //it is still string
$time = $time+$time;
echo $time; //output is still 120
```

In this case, you don't need to convert a string to int, instantly it is there. In addition, for time variables I strongly suggest you to use DateTime format which is explained in detailed here http://php.net/manual/tr/class.datetime.php